# Removed the Ethernet cable in active SIP and RTP session

Tags: sip, sip-server

I have below SIP call scenario:
A party --> Proxy --> B party

Session is established and RTP is flowing, what will happen if I remove the Ethernet cable of A party ?? How the session will be terminated and what about RTP session ?

Comment: Not a programming question. This depends mainly on 2 items: 1. SIP signaling level, if you have SIP session refresh, it may timeout and call will be dropped. 2. Media level, if your endpoints support RTP timeout they will detect no RTP is arriving and call will be dropped. You need to be more specific about software you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the ideal solution is

1) Since the party B is not receiving any audio, it should terminate the call after certain configured time out. This is not a standard thing. An approach.

2) Once B disconnects, at proxy call is disconnected. Proxy will send BYE to A. Since A will never answer (as no connectivity), it times out at proxy, and proxy cleans up the call. This is as per standard.

3) Now it is again implementation specific. Application at A should clean up the call as there is no connectivity. When connectivity is lost, ideally application gets callback or some mechanism to know of link disconnect. That should be the trigger to free up all resources used for call.